# How to send URL parameter variable through datatables to my controller - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I am attempting to pass a URL variable from a vehicle page that would filter the expenses create for the selected vehicle. The page renders but I am receiving a message saying please see http://datatables.net/tn/1 which I assume the variable is not reaching the controller. Please help me with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

**index.blade**

```
var vehicleexpensetable = $('#vehicleexpensetable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{{action('\Modules\Essentials\Http\Controllers\VehicleExpenseController@index', request()->route('id'))}}",
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 2,
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
        },
    ]
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/vehicleexpenses/{id}','VehicleExpenseController@index');
```

**VehicleExpenseController**

```
public function index($id)
{
    $BusinessID = request()->session()->get('user.business_id');

    if (!auth()->user()->can('vehicle.view') && !auth()->user()->can('vehicle.create')) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    if (request()->ajax()) {


        $vehicleexpense = VehicleExpense::where('vehicle_expenses.BusinessID', $BusinessID)
                    ->where('vehicle_expenses.VehicleID', $id)
                    ->join('expense_types as et', 'et.id', '=', 'vehicle_expenses.expense_type_id')
                    ->select([
                        'vehicle_expenses.id',
                        'et.ExpenseType',
                        'Expense',
                        'Amount',
                        'Location',
                        'CompletedDate',
                        'vehicle_expenses.BusinessID',
                        'Note'
                        ]);

        return Datatables::of($vehicleexpense)
            ->addColumn(
                'action',
                '@can("vehicle.update")
                <button data-href="{{action(\'\Modules\Essentials\Http\Controllers\VehicleExpenseController@edit\', [$id])}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-modal" data-container=".view_modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>  @lang("messages.edit")</button>
                    &nbsp;
                @endcan
                @can("vehicle.delete")
                    <button data-href="{{action(\'\Modules\Essentials\Http\Controllers\VehicleExpenseController@destroy\', [$id])}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_vehicleexpensebutton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> @lang("messages.delete")</button>
                @endcan'
            )
            ->editColumn('CompletedDate', function ($row) {
                $CompletedDate = \Carbon::parse($row->CompletedDate);
                $CompletedDate_formated = $this->moduleUtil->format_date($CompletedDate);
                return $CompletedDate_formated;
            })
            ->removeColumn('id','BusinessID')
            ->rawColumns([6])
            ->make(false);
    }


    $expensetypes = ExpenseType::forDropdown($BusinessID);

    $vehicle = Vehicle::where('BusinessID', $BusinessID)
                ->find($id);

    return view('essentials::vehicleexpense.index')->with(compact('expensetypes','vehicle'));
}
```